# Filter by a certain column as well as with multiple columns in table using AngularJS

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I have one filterby dropdown and one search textbox. In the dropdown, I am dividing it into two search items, i.e one is "None" which will filter all the columns in the table (whole table) and second part is containing rest of the column names present in the table which will filter with respect to their name.

On selection of "None" it is searching whole table and displaying the result.
Now the problem is when i am selecting some other field from dropdown and trying to write something in the search textbox, it is not enabling me to type anything.

Below is the code I am using:

```
<div class="row filterbyHeading">
    FilterBy<br>
    </div><!-- End of FilterBy heading -->
    <div class="row">
    <select ng-style="{"width": getMaxLength()}" class="filterbyTextbox" id="filterSearch" ng-model="filterSearch">
    <option value="None">None</option>
    <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
    <option value="Mango">Mango</option>
    <option value="Banana">Banana</option>
    <option value="Pineapple">Pineapple</option>
    </select>

    <!--search function to search data in table-->
    <input type="search" id="Search1" ng-model="search" class="form-control searchTextbox" placeholder="Search"/>
    <input type="search" id="Search2" ng-model="search[filterSearch]" class="form-control searchTextbox" placeholder="Search Filter"/>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Script for the above code:

```
<script>

    $("#Search1").show();
    $("#Search2").hide();
    $(document).on("change", "#filterSearch", function() {
   var selectedValue = $(this.selectedOptions).text();
      if(selectedValue==="None"){
        $("#Search1").show();
        $("#Search2").hide();
        $("#Search1").val('');
        $("#Search2").val('');
     }else{
        $("#Search1").hide();
        $("#Search2").show();

        $("#Search1").val('');
        $("#Search2").val('');
     } 
   });


</script>
```

[image]

Comment: If you really want to learn Angular the first step is to remove jQuery from you project. Completely. Then you will be forced to do things properly.

Comment: @dfsq: can you please give solution to this problem using Angular as i tried so many things but didn't get exact solution that's why i opted for jquery.

Comment: You already have ngModel, now you just need to add filters (to your ngRepeat): https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter